# Pass *args in django templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I did use django pagination, but there is a problem with urls, here is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^/blog/$', blog_view.main, name='blog'),    
url(r'^/blog/page/(?P<page_id>\d{0,9})$', blog.post, name='blog_page'),
```

My views.py:

```
def post(request, page_id=None):
    posts = Posts.objects.all()
    pageid = page_id
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'posts': posts, 'pageid': pageid,})
```

My base.html which use bootstrap:

```
{% url 'blog_page' as blog_page %} # Blog page need follow patterns
    <ul>
{% for post in posts %}
    <li {% if request.path == htt://myblog.com/blog/page/5 %} class="active" {% endif %}>{{ post.title }}</li> # When I put blog_page django shows error. Help me how to put something to fix this condition.
{% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Comment: And do you fancy telling us what the problem is, perhaps?

Comment: If someone clicked on a page (ex: when request.path was /page/5) that page should have active class.

Comment: {% url 'blog_page' page_id %}

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documenation on HttpRequest objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/), 
`HttpRequest.path` is

> A string representing the full path to the requested page, **not including the scheme or domain.**
>   Example: "/music/bands/the_beatles/"

(emphasis mine).

So, in your test, leave out the scheme (which you, btw, incorrectly wrote as `htt://`) and domain parts:

```
<li {% if request.path == /blog/page/5 %} class="active" {% endif %}>{{ post.title }}</li>
```

Comment: That's nice, Is there any way to change that 5 with a dynamic id?